# ScriptSharp: Converting class into JavaScript object on selected metadata

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, script#

Imagine you have two ScriptSharp classes like the following:

```
public class Person {
    public int Weight;
    public Name Name;
    public int Height;
}

public class Name { 
   public string FirstName;
   public string LastName;
}
```

How can I get ScriptSharp to generate the following in the output JS ?

```
var object1 = {
  weight: 0,
  name: {firstname: 'fname1', lastname: 'srn1'},
  height: 97
};

instead of

var object1 = {};
object1.weight = 0;
object1.height = 97;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually there will be language support for object literals.

In the mean time you can use the technique demonstrated with the CustomDictionary class in one of the script# tests - see https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/blob/master/tests/TestCases/Expression/New/Code.cs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes it would be a good feature to add to Script#